# Can't get Icon font/sprite rollover to change colors

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

I am trying to to position some related icons above my main nav. Essentially what am I am trying to accomplish is to have the text and icon change to a different color when the user hovers over the appropriate area (the  tag with large padding). I am having problems accomplishing that.

My thinking is that it would be easiest to do it with icon fonts, but they are inline only. I then tried to make a new  with the icon fonts and position them above the man nav, but then I couldn't figure out how to get it to change colors when the user hovered over the designated area.

I also tried the rollover method, which I couldn't get to work, because when I made a class in the  tag and changed the display to block, it threw my nav off. My code:

```
 <ul id="nav" role="navigation">
   <li><a href="#">EXCERPT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

#header {
   overflow: hidden;
   background-color: #F5F5F5;
   border-bottom: 2px black solid;
   position: relative;
}

#nav {
   float: right;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   right: 0;
   margin: 0 0 10px 0;
}

#nav li {
   list-style: none;
   display: inline;
   font-size: 2.5em;
   letter-spacing: 0.1em;
   font-family: 'OstrichSansMedium';
}

#nav a {
   text-decoration: none;
   color: #C4C4C4;
   padding: 200px 20px 15px;
}

#nav a:hover {
   color: #000000;
   background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: It seems to work somewhat .. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Well I can't figure out a way, be it via font icons or sprite rollovers, to place icons right above the nav and have them too change to a different color/position when a user hovers over the <a> tag area.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to do a fiddle for you but jsfiddle is down for maint.  You're going to have to use a little bit of script to handle a complex bar with images, etc.  Sprites are very nice and effective but again you'll need at least a few lines of script to support it

Take a look at the source of the [tabs on jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).  The structure you have above is nothing more than a tab bar.

Look at this site too. [Live Example](http://www.universal-american-medicare.com) The top navigation is all done with images, CSS and a tiny bit of jQuery. Grab the source on this one too so you can view it any time.

Comment: Hmm I see. I was really hoping for a pure CSS solution as I don't know any programming.

Comment: If you were working with a simple hover for x number of elements then yes but when you're dealing with multiple elements and states you need something to control it.  You can probably find something already coded that does exactly what you want.  Look around on [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) and [jQueryUI](http://www.jqueryui.com) at some of the API and the examples. You never know, may be something that you understand.

Comment: Is there anyway to position icon fonts above text?

Comment: EDIT: Yes, I just changed the position to absolute on the "[data-icon]:before" selector and moved it around with negative margins. Looks like problem = solved.

Comment: @vytfla that's great, so everything is working like you need it to?

Comment: pretty much; I was able to move the icons around (in this case, placing them above my text) and I was able to space them out evenly, but now I am trying to individually move one from the stack and am having trouble.

Comment: Do you have a wireframe, an image or anything you can share which demonstrates what the ultimate goal is?

Comment: http://imgur.com/MBuqNKv: the nav and their hover state. You can see that the 'about' icon isn't centered while the other two sort of are, and it's because they all have equal margins; I am having trouble changing messing around with individual margins because this is being done through the [data-icon]:before selector.